# How to pass mongodb database connection through routes in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I need to pass the connection to mongo from index.js to the other routes, I think it is possible to create a file with the instructions that define the connection with the database, so that I can recall it within the other routes, but I have no idea how it can be done. The other examples on this forum didn't help me a lot. I will attach the code below.

```
//Database connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/codingWaifus", {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Connected to "+mongoose.connection.name+" on Port: "+mongoose.connection.port);
  }
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Comment: Do you need the raw connection to the db? Mongoose usually works with models that do the querying for you. If you only need to work with the models you can just leave the connection in your index.js file and require the models in your routes and use them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way:

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

const connectDB = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

    mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => { 
        console.log('Connection to the DB established');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => { 
        console.log('Error occured while connecting to the DB', err);
    })
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**index.js**

```
const connectDB = require('./db');
 
// Connecting to the DB
connectDB();
```

But why do you want to call the MongoDB connection again when you have already established the connection on the first place?

Comment: Because i need to perform some querys inside some routes

Comment: @GigiCarti Does my answer solves your problem